# Android Junit Test stuck at "Launching: Creating source locator..."

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing, motionevent

**EDIT**

 After some debugging, I realised that the entire test was not running. However strangely, it worked a few times and when I tried it again, it failed to run. Under the progress tab, it was always stuck at "Launching: Creating source locator..." and the test was not executed.

I tried restarting eclipse but I could not get it to work.

I am a newbie to android testing and I want to generate touch events to test the pause and play of a video in an android app. I use the Android Testing Framework to select the video and play it, and the video starts running fine, but the touch event does not execute, nor does the test end. I tried debugging, but the touchlistener was never called when the tests ran. I am not sure why the code execution doesn't reach the MotionEvents part. Really would appreciate your help!

```
public class VideoPlaybackTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private Activity activity;
private Fragment localvideosfragment;
private VideoPlayer videoplayer;
private ZoomState zoomstate;
private RenderView renderView;

public VideoPlaybackTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);

    activity = getActivity();
    FragmentManager fragmentmanager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    localvideosfragment = fragmentmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
}

@Test
public void testVideoSelection() {

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            assertNotNull(localvideosfragment);
            View rootView = (View) localvideosfragment.getView();
            ListView videolist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            assertNotNull(videolist);
            // Select video to play 
            videolist.performItemClick(videolist.getChildAt(0), 0, videolist.getChildAt(0).getId());
        }
    });

    // Wait for VideoPlayer Activity to be started
    ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(VideoPlayer.class.getName(), null, false);
    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();

    // get the started video player Activity
    videoplayer = (VideoPlayer) instrumentation.waitForMonitor(monitor);
    assertNotNull(videoplayer);

    // Get zoomstate and assert that video is playing 
    renderView = videoplayer.getRenderView();
    assertNotNull(renderView);
    zoomstate = renderView.getZoomState();
    assertNotNull(zoomstate);
    ROIState roistate = renderView.getROIState();
    Boolean isPlaying = roistate.isPlaying;
    assertTrue(zoomstate.isPlaying());
    assertTrue(isPlaying);

    // Obtain MotionEvent object
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent motionEventup = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, 
            eventTime, 
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
            x, 
            y, 
            metaState
            );
    MotionEvent motionEventdown = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, 
            eventTime, 
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
            x, 
            y, 
            metaState
            );

    renderView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventdown);
    renderView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventup);
    roistate = renderView.getROIState();
    isPlaying = roistate.isPlaying;
    zoomstate = renderView.getZoomState();
    Boolean state = zoomstate.isPlaying();
    assertFalse(state);
    assertFalse(isPlaying);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found a way to make it work. I had uninstall the existing app from the device, and start afresh. The tests ran fine after that.

Comment: In my case the test app was 'invisible', so I was able delete it only via `adb uninstall`

Comment: @miazima Do you mean uninstalling the app-being-tested or the app which is testing?